# Como realizar una peticion POST multipart con retorno de un JSON de respuesta en Android studio y PHP bakend

Tags: php, android, android-studio, webservice, restful

Buen día ante todo.
Tengo un Servicio REST multipart que responde a solicitudes POST para subir un file y además un texto para realizar la operación, todo esto en PHP. al terminar de realizar la operación devuleve un JSON como respuesta.
Entonces desde android se debe poder realizar esta acción. El detalle esta en que realiza la solicitud y devuelve un 200.
Aquí Abajo ire explicando más a detalle.

1. WebService en Php multipart

   ```
   public static function decode_body2($body)
   {
           $chat=new jchat_entidad();
           $chat->setChat_tip($body['chat_tip']); 
           $chat->setChat_ext($body['chat_ext']);
           $chat->setChat_emi($body['chat_emi']);
           $chat->setChat_recep($body['chat_recep']); 
           $chat->setChat_write($body['chat_write']);
           $chat->setChatsala_ide($body['chatsala_ide']);
           }
           return $chat;
   }
   ```

   esta es la clase principal

   ```
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

   try {
       $jsonContent=json_encode($_POST["JSON_CONTENT"]);
       $Body=json_decode($jsonContent,true);
       //print_r($Body);
       //Recjo del parseo de Datos
       //$sala=Json_Convert::decode_Head($Body["Cabeza"]);
       $chat=Json_Convert::decode_body2($Body["Chat"]);
       $idPetition=$Body["Petition"];
       //print_r($sala);
       //print_R($chat);
       if(isset($_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]))
       {
           $name=$_FILES["upload_file"]["name"];
           $tmp_name=$_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"];       
           $error=$_FILES["upload_file"]["error"];
           $size=$_FILES["upload_file"]["size"];
           $tipe=$_FILES["upload_file"]["type"];
           //echo "name  ".$name;
           //echo " | tmp_name ".$tmp_name;
           //echo " | error ".$error;
           //echo " | size ".$size;
           //echo " | tipe ".$tipe ." | ";
           //si el tamaño es menor a 8MB
           if($error==0)
           {//no hay errores en el proceo de subida del file
               if($size<=8912896) //Comparacion en bytes
               {//el file esta deacuerdo con lo que se necesita para guardarlo

                   switch ($chat->getChat_tip()) {
                       case 2:
                           //if($tipe=="image/jpeg" OR $tipe=="image/jpg" OR $tipe=="image/png")
                           if($tipe==Mime_types::evaluator_Image($chat->getChat_ext()))
                           {//Tipo Imagen
                               $info=new SplFileInfo($name);
                               $chat->setChat_msg(basename($name,'.'.$info->getExtension()));
                               $Result=Chat_Controlador::Menssage_Common($chat,$tmp_name,$idPetition);
                               if($Result)
                               {
                                   print json_encode($Result);

                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   print json_encode(array('status' =>2 , 'Menssage'=>"not content",'Content'=>'not' ));
                               }
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               print json_encode(array('status' =>3 , 'Menssage'=>"incoherente files case 2",'Content'=>'not' ));
                           }
                           break;
                       case 3:
                           //if($tipe=="application/pdf" OR $tipe=="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" OR  $tipe=="application/vnd.ms-excel" OR $tipe=="application / vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" OR $tipe=="application/msword")
                           if($tipe==Mime_types::evaluator_Document($chat->getChat_ext()))
                           {//Tipo documento
                               $info=new SplFileInfo($name);
                               $chat->setChat_msg(basename($name,'.'.$info->getExtension()));
                               $Result=Chat_Controlador::Menssage_Common($chat,$tmp_name,$idPetition);
                               if($Result)
                               {
                                   print json_encode($Result);
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   print json_encode(array('status' =>2 , 'Menssage'=>"not content",'Content'=>'not' ));
                               }
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               print json_encode(array('status' =>3 , 'Menssage'=>"incoherente files case 3",'Content'=>'not' ));
                           }
                           break;
                       default:
                           print json_encode(array('status' =>4 , 'Menssage'=>"incoherente operation",'Content'=>'not' ));
                           break;
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   //echo "Archivo excede la capacidad predeterminada de 8 MB";
                   print json_encode(array('status' =>30 ,'Menssage'=>"File Excede capacidad maxima",'Content'=>'not'));
               }
           }
           else
           {
               //echo "Hubo erores en el proceso de subida";
               print json_encode(array('status' =>31 ,'Menssage'=>"Hubo errores en el proceso de upload",'Content'=>'not'));
           }

       }
       else
       {
           //echo "no existe file adjunto";
           print json_encode(array('status' =>32 ,'Menssage'=>"not File",'Content'=>'not'));
       }


   } catch (Exception $e) {
       //echo "Error de parseo de JSON";
       print json_encode(array('status' =>33 ,'Menssage'=>"Error parsing",'Content'=>'not'));

   }
   }
   ```

   En el codigo de arriba recibo el la peticion funciona (adjunto prueba de postman)
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. ANDROID

para realizar la peticion estoy usando OkHttp3 realiza la coneccion pero nunca obtengo el JSON de respuesta, ni algun error solo obtengo status 200.
Adjuto el codigo

```
private void send_file2(chat_entidad chat) {
    File f = new File(chat.getChat_file());
    String Name_Archivo = f.getName();
    String file_path = chat.getChat_file();
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("JSON_CONTENT[Chat][chat_tip]", String.valueOf(chat.getChat_tip()))
            .addFormDataPart("JSON_CONTENT[Chat][chat_emi]", String.valueOf(chat.getChat_emi()))
            .addFormDataPart("JSON_CONTENT[Chat][chat_recep]", String.valueOf(chat.getChat_recep()))
            .addFormDataPart("JSON_CONTENT[Chat][chat_write]", String.valueOf(chat.getChat_write()))
            .addFormDataPart("JSON_CONTENT[Chat][chat_ext]", String.valueOf(chat.getChat_ext()))
            .addFormDataPart("JSON_CONTENT[Chat][chatsala_ide]", String.valueOf(chat.getChatsala_ide()))
            .addFormDataPart("JSON_CONTENT[Petition]", String.valueOf(chat.getChat_idPetition()))
            .addFormDataPart("upload_file", file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1),
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"), f))
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("url/sendfile_Multipart_Service.php")
            .post(requestBody)
            .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response)
                throws IOException {
            Log.e("Okhhttp", "Bien");
            Log.e("responce", response.body().toString());
        }

        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.e("Okhhttp", "Fallo");
        }
    });
}
```

Lo que neceisto es poder subir file y además poder obtener los Datos en textoplano que envio en el servidor.Y al terminar la operación el servidro me devuelve un JSON de respuesta y este JSON tengo que obtenerlo y decodificarlo desde android. Desde ya agradesco su ayuda y su tiempo. Si hay alguna forma mejor de realizar esta misma operación por favor compartan. Saludos

Comment: ¿Revisaste el logcat? No conozco `OkHttp3` pero no veo claro donde manejas la respuesta del servidor ¿? Por lógica debería ser aquí: `public void onResponse(Call call, Response response)
                throws IOException {` pero sólo veo que intentas manejar ahí el caso de `IOException` ... ¿dónde manejas las respuestas exitosas?

Comment: la respuesta de la petición exitosa va al método `public void onResponse(Call call, Response response)
                throws IOException {
            Log.e("Okhhttp", "Bien");
            Log.e("responce", response.body().toString());
        } ` dentro del objeto response se obtiene la respuesta. lo he estado imprimiendo en en un Log. lo he debuegueado para saber si existe algún error pero siempre da lo mismo. @A.Cedano